# protractor custom expected condition fails with error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to wait the browser with `browser.wait` with a custom ExpectedCondition like this
The FunctionReturningANumber returns only a number and the numberToCheck is the number to check the number for.

```
var conditionFn = function () {
    return functionReturningANumber(param) === numberToCheck;
};

var condition = EC.and(conditionFn);
browser.wait(condition, 50000);
```

But if I execute this, I get the error: `fn(...).then is not a function` which basically says, that it expects an promise. I have looked up the documentation about ExpectedConditions, and the example for a custom one is like this:

```
// You can define your own expected condition, which is a function that
// takes no parameter and evaluates to a promise of a boolean.
var urlChanged = function() {
     return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
      return url === 'http://www.angularjs.org';
   });
};
```

And I do not see how here a promise is created. I only see, that a boolean is returned, and the documentation says `evaluates to a promise of a boolean` which confuses me even more.

This above is for waiting a response from an API, this is caused, because the test triggers a backend process, which protractor then needs to wait for. If there is any better way of doing this, I would greatly appreciate a better way.

I am using protractor 3.1.1.

Any help really apprectiated.

Edit:

I found a way to solve this, for some reason the logical solution by @alecxe didn't work, even if it makes sense:

```
var numberFound = 0;
var done = false;
var check = function () {
    numberFound = functionReturnungANumber(param);
    if (numberFound != numberToCheck) {
        setTimeout(check, 4000);
    } else {
        done = true;
    }
};
check();
return done;
```

If I add this to the function and retrieve the return value in the test, which calls this function, and add a `browser.wait(function () {
            return done;
        });` there it works.

It's not beautiful, but for some reason, its the only thing working.... for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that you don't need to wrap your Expected Condition function into `EC.and`:

```
browser.wait(conditionFn, 5000);
```

Comment: It doesn't return a promise, and I tried this once before, but now if I do something like this: `var conditionFn = function () {
        var result = functionReturningANumber(param) === numberToCheck;
        console.log(result)
        return result;
    };

    browser.wait(conditionFn, 50000);`
it will print `false` a lot of times and then just exit. For testing I changed, that this condition will never happen, but it just exits, as the condition would have been fulfilled.

Comment: @Sheldan please see the update - a wild guess, but give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: If I change it to that, it wont print anything. If I change it to be `conditionFn()` it will execute obviously, as its the same as before, but only for a number of times, before it quits. Is there maybe some kind of timeout or number of executions you perhaps know of?

Comment: @Sheldan well, it should be executed while it evaluates to `false` until the timeout is reached (5 seconds in this case). Once it returns `true` it would stop executing the function..Is not it how it behaves in your case? Thanks.

Comment: No, if I add the `console.log`, it will print about 300 times `false` and then quit without ever printing `true`. This is the only test I execute, if that matters.

Comment: @Sheldan well, it sounds like `browser.wait()` does it's job. Are you sure the condition ever evaluates to true? What if you would just return `true` from  the `conditionFn`?

Comment: For some reason it only does its job outside of this, in a page object, but if i use it in that `exports` function, it waits a number of times and then exits. I printed it and it was a bunch of `false` then exit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
browser.wait(conditionFn () {
    return url === 'http://www.angularjs.org';
}, 8000);
```